Rshiny unexpected behaviour with images
I am quite a newbie to Shiny apps but I managed to build an interface that allows me to choose from a list of image urls based on the images that can be found at the url. The app works fine when I do Run App on RStudio but as soon as I try to call it from an external function, the images are no longer shown (only thumbnails). Since the script is quite long, I managed after a bit of debbugging to recreate the effect on a MRE that is based on the shiny project example.
library(shiny)

app_ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
    
    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins and an image
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
            # Inserting the image
            img(src = "/prova/1.jpg", height = "300px", width = "100%")
        ),
        
        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
app_server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
        
        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white',
             xlab = 'Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)',
             main = 'Histogram of waiting times')
    })
}

# Run the application 
app <- shinyApp(ui = app_ui, server = app_server)

If I then have a different R script (external.R) where I call the app contained in file  MainApp.R like so, the image breaks down.
source("path_to_app/MainApp.R")
app



In fact I noticed an even stranger behaviour. If I first Run App the app, the images are displayed correctly also when sourcing from an external file. If I clean the environment and try to source directly, the images are not shown. It seems almost like the images are cached somewhere.
My folder structure is
Shinyapp
   |- MainApp.R
   |- external.R
   |- www
    | |- prova
      | |- 1.jpg



Your folder structure and request path is correct. As the shiny docs note:

Static files under the www/ directory are automatically made available under a request path that begins with /

The odd thing is that the image is displayed at all when you source external.R. I suspect it might be some RStudio magic, and if you open the URL in a browser you will not see the image.
In any case, the issue is that you're using shiny::shinyApp(), which creates an app from a server and ui R object.
However, you need the context of the directory and subdirectory, so you want to use shiny::runApp(), to pass the current folder.
shiny::runApp() expects either a ui.R and server.R, or an app.R. So in your case, rename mainApp.R to app.R, and then the contents of external.R can simply be:
shiny::runApp()



I am trying your solution but I am not sure I get it. I changed the name of MainApp.R to app.R. Then I switched the last line of that file from app <- shinyApp(ui = app_ui, server = app_server) to shiny::RunApp(ui = app_ui, server = app_server) and external.R is now shiny::runApp(). When I try to execute this last line I get Error: 'RunApp' is not an exported object from 'namespace:shiny' 

@Manfredo no need to change anything in app.R. The final line should remain app <- shinyApp(ui = app_ui, server = app_server). It's only external.R that needs to change to shiny::runApp().

I keep getting the same error though > shiny::runApp() Error: 'RunApp' is not an exported object from 'namespace:shiny' 

@Manfredo are you sure you are doing shiny::runApp() with a lower case r? Your error message is referrng to RunApp

Ok, it works. Unfortunately I realize now that the MRE problem is possibly not the same of the main app which is packed into a function and receives a dataframe as input. I will try to figure it out or open a new ticket.

@Manfredo that sounds different enough that I'd suggest accepting one of the existing answers if they solve the problem, and asking a new question.

Though if you switch the geyser image with a different one, still called 1.jpg, the old geyser image will show up at runtime. Maybe it is due to some weird caching

@Manfredo yes it's just the browser cache

EDIT 2 - Ok solution definitely works. Had a "/" in front of prova. Full solution below in case I loose it again.
In MainApp.R
library(shiny)

app_ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins and an image
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
      # Inserting the image
      img(src = "prova/1.png", height = "300px", width = "100%")
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
app_server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    
    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white',
         xlab = 'Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)',
         main = 'Histogram of waiting times')
  })
}

# Run the application 
app <- shinyApp(ui = app_ui, server = app_server)

In external.R:
source("G:/app/MainApp.R")
app


EDIT - Solution not working anymore. Pretty sure I tested before I posted the answer, please disregard. Leaving the answer instead of deleting so that others can see it was one option that was investigated.

I moved the prova folder out of the www folder and put in a root folder called app:
app
   |- MainApp.R
   |- external.R
   | |- prova
     | |- 1.jpg
   |- www

Then adjust the image source line to:
img(src = "prova/1.png")


This loads the image correctly both when I Run App and source the entire script through an external script

Yes, I had indeed tested that option before and it didn't work for me. I guess the content has to be stored in www  though I was not sure wether subdirectories in www were ok.

Apologies @Manfredo I have updated my solution (again lol). Please check again
